# Fix footer to the bottom of page in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How can I fix the footer to the bottom of the screen even when there is not enough content in the page?
I mean when the page is empty the footer jumps up taking half half the screen

I tried to set the content height to 100% the size of screen, less the heights of header & footer, with the following:

```
#main {
min-height: calc(100% - 80px - 70px);
}
```

But the 100% equals 0px since the content (nested inside the #main) is empty

How do I take the 100% from  instead?

I asked the same on wordpress.org and they directed me to SO for this type of issue

Ref:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fix-footer-to-the-bottom-of-screen/

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQjtW.png)

Comment: link of the site?

Comment: http://www.sun-tex.co.il/test2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the css to footer :

```
.footer-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

For wrapper,

```
#wrapper, #main{
 position: static !important;
}
```

Comment: Halfway there, the footer is now fixed to bottom but it's wrapper/background still fill up the screen: https://s2.postimg.org/a7jgxthxl/Untitled.png I think it is the #main content height that needs adjustment

Comment: remove position: relative;  from header.

Comment: working great, only that the header shadow disappeared, how do I fix that? https://s22.postimg.org/5c1d50x8x/Untitled.png

Comment: Add header{box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;}, adjust the shadow as you need.

Comment: It works while the `.header {position:relative}`  is active, when I remove the `position:relative` from header, the box-shadow isn't responding, unsure why

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you could try this, let me know if it works

```
.footer{
top: 100vh;
transform: translate(-100%,0);
position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: `#main {
top: 100vh;
transform: translate(-100%,0);
position:fixed;
}` result: https://image.ibb.co/hnrPvk/Untitled.png

Comment: `#footer { top: 100vh; transform: translate(-100%,0); position:fixed; }` result: https://image.ibb.co/djthgQ/Untitled2.png

Answer (score 0):

the best and simplest way to set the footer at the bottom once and for all is as following!

1- create a div content in your css and give the following properties

```
.content{ min-height: 100vh}
```

2- in your worpress page template add this

```
<div class="content"> place all your content inside this div or your loops   </div>
```

if you wonder how the page template will look after adding this here is the full example

```html
<?php get_header();?>


<div class="container>
    <div class="content">
        
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()):?>
    
          <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('largest');?>" class="img-fluid">
    
        <?php endif;?>
        
        
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
    
            <?php the_content();?>
    
        <?php endwhile; endif;?>
    
    
    </div>

</div>


<?php get_footer();?>
```

after you do this the footer will always stay to the bottom even if the page is empty and also no extra space or anything else!

enjoy